# Getting url where redirection is coming from

Tags: php, redirect

i have three pages page1.php, page2.php and page3.php. Page1 and page2 redirect to page3. Depending on where the redirection is coming from I want it to display something. How do i get where the redirection is coming from.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reliably, the simplest way is to add a GET variable e.g. `http://example.com/page3?from=page1`

Comment: @Abdul Thanks I had the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the $_SERVER variable:
http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Check the variable content and to use for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

HTTP_REFERER

The address of the page (if any) which referred 
the user agent to the current page. This is set by 
the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, 
and some provide the ability to modify 
HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot 
really be trusted.

You can read more about this here

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Here is small example that shows how you can print the referer url:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```